# Duplicate values in Xml database

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to insert only unique values in my XML database based on the "userName" value. For example there can't be two players which has same name in the database. The implementation of my xml database which is named as "MyXML.xml" is like that :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <Players>
         <player name="cag" score="5555" />
         <player name="cihan" score="1222" />
         <player name="can" score="333" />
     </Players>
```

and my related code in order to detetect duplication is:

```
      public bool insertUserDetails(string userName,float userScore){


           XDocument doc = Document.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("MyXML.xml"));

           var duplicate = doc.Element("Players").Elements("player").Where(x =>(string)x.Value == userName).SingleOrDefault();

           if (duplicate != null){

               return false;

          }
          else{
               return true;
         }
     }
```

when I try to insert a duplicate value for example "can" and "333",  var duplicate value turns out to be null. How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're comparing the value of an XElement, "x", to userName.

you should compare the "name" attribute of x to it.

```
var duplicate = doc.Element("Players").Elements("player").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name").Value == userName).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

"can" is defined as a attribute in your XML; It is not a value. Value is something which comes in between open and closing tags of xml.

For example, if you have a xml element like this

```
<SomeTag name="somename">Hello world</SomeTag>
```

Then, `SomeTag` is the element name, `somename` is the attribute value of attribute "name" and "Hello world" is the value of the xml element itself.

So, You need to find the attribute using `Attribute` method to access its value.

```
var duplicate = doc.Element("Players")
                    .Elements("player")
                    .Where(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value == userName)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: your explanation is better than mine. so +1

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of each `player` element, rather than the Attributes of those elements. Since there's no text inside the `player` element, the `value` is always an empty string, and thus never matched the name you're looking for. Instead, select the [`.GetAttribute("name")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7(v=vs.110).aspx) for each element

```
var duplicate = doc
    .Element("Players")
    .Elements("player")
    .Select(ele => ele.GetAttribute("name"))
    .Where(att =>(string)att.Value == userName)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```